# MYSQL Double Join on information with same column name

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically These are the tables in theory i have.

```
item
 -----------------------------
|  Item_id  |  Item Name     |  
 -----------------------------
|  1        |    car         |        
 -----------------------------
|  2        |    door       |          
 -----------------------------

car
 -----------------------------
|  Car_id  |  Car registered |  
 -----------------------------
|  1        |    blah blah   |        
 -----------------------------

house
 -----------------------------
|  House_id  | date_register |  
 -----------------------------
|  2        |    blah bla    |        
 -----------------------------

houseOwn
 ----------------------
|  House_id  | Car_id |  
 ----------------------
|  1        |      2  |        
 ----------------------
```

Basically i want it so that using the houseOwn table i can show the house item name and car item name fields like below.

```
 ------------------------
|  House_Name | Car_Name |  
 ----------------------
|  Door      |      Car |        
 ----------------------
```

I've messed around with the actual code and only got as far as showing both columns as showing door (in my actual database i'm using different values as it's nothing to do with doors or cars this is just for show).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: your output is misleading. do you want the output to be house | Car ?

Comment: The example is invalid: there is nowhere a "Door" in it. I believe, you should read up about `as` syntax in `select`, both for tables and fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can inner join 3 of the tables with a query like this:

`select * from houseOwn as a
 inner join house as b on a.House_id = b.House_id
 inner join car as c on a.Car_id = c.Car_id;`

as far as i can see you cant directly include Item_id as Item_id is not referenced in any other table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only require the item name and not the details of items, try something like this

```
SELECT IH.Item_Name as House_Name,IC.Item_Name as Car_Name,
FROM houseOwn as HO
INNER JOIN item as IH
ON HO.House_id = IH.item_id
INNER JOIN item as IC
ON HO.Car_ID  = IC.item_id
```

Comment: When i used that it came up with this error Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[last_name] as Doctors_Name, LP. [last_name] as Patients_name, FROM appointmen' at line 1

Comment: @Identicon, so why didn't you tell us your running MySQL? Here you got a SQL Server answer...

Comment: try without []. these were specific to SQL Server